# How to run userscript(/greasemonkey) after AngularJS library is loaded

Tags: angularjs, userscripts

I just want to create some extensions to angular object to make AngularJS debugging more convenient.

But when I run add userscript, it can't find an angular object. AngularJS library is loaded in the bottom of  tag.

**UPD**: @estus provided right answer, but if you want to use chrome you need to install it via [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) extension.

You can find final code snippet [here](https://github.com/stevermeister/userscripts/blob/master/angular-shortcuts.user.js).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that Angular is unavailable at the moment when user script runs indicates that Angular is loaded asynchronously, this is quite normal for any SPA (also check that [@run-at](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) is *not* set to `document-start`, it isn't the desirable behaviour here).

The usual workaround for user scripts is to watch for the desired variable:

```
var initWatcher = setInterval(function () {
    console.log('watch');
    if (unsafeWindow.angular) {
        clearInterval(initWatcher);
        init();
    }
}, 100);

function init() {
    console.log('angular', unsafeWindow.angular);
}
```

If cross-browser compatibility is not required, then FF-specific [Object.prototype.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Object.watch) can be used instead:

```
unsafeWindow.watch('angular', function (prop, oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log('watch');
    if (newVal) {
        unsafeWindow.unwatch('angular');
        // angular is still undefined ATM, run init() a bit later
        setTimeout(init);
    }
    return newVal;
});

function init() {
    console.log('angular', unsafeWindow.angular);
}
```

Comment: Essentially correct but will not always work as expected, depending on the userscript engine and the `@grant` mode. OP did not provide sufficient detail.  Script injection may be needed (and is the only universal way).  Or, it may be smarter just to `@require` a separate copy of angular for the script scope -- on engines that support `@require`.

Comment: @BrockAdams Right, security permissions will be different even for different GM versions (I believe the last problem-free was 1.x), and dreaded 'permission denied' for unsafeWindow is trivial. A separate copy won't solve the problem because Angular app state is stored within `angular` object. But doing `@require` before Angular was loaded on the page may help - Angular [won't redefine](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/angular.suffix#L1) `window.angular`, and GM script can just define it first.

Comment: thank you for detailed answer. It's weird but it still does not work. It can't find "unsafeWindow.angular" that's why in console I see many "watch" lines. Put the code here - https://github.com/stevermeister/userscripts/blob/master/angular-shortcuts.user.js

Comment: @STEVER What's your userscipt environment? I've checked it and got it working as it should on arbitrary site (docs.angularjs.org), Greasemonkey 3.2. I like the idea, I found myself digging to injector from console a few times. Modified it a bit to my needs, feel free to [use it](http://0bin.net/paste/hj8QPoxIj05sQN3Q#sV5PRHgvYc1Qg9jetGeHNTyyunQFZP06qGpY0QlZM5c).

Comment: I'm using it with chrome and it does not work with docs.angularjs.org. For you script it goes to "watch ng" 21 times and stops.

Comment: @STEVER Change `@grant none` to `@grant unsafeWindow`, this one is specific to Tampermonkey afaik.

Comment: great, thanks a lot! it works for me only when I install it via Tampermonkey

Comment: Sure, never dealt with native Chrome userscripts but they may have their kinks (they won't have unsafeWindow, for starters). Good one on `document.querySelector('[src*="angular"]')`, it should cover 99% of cases.

Comment: Hi.. I need to do the same thing, but I need to open a url (may be $window.open) and then run my user scripts there. How do I do it?

Comment: why code like this only works inside an extension like ViolentMonkey but not as extension it self?

Comment: @ChopLabalagun Because in an extension you don't have the access to DOM globals that exist in regular browser environment, I guess. And `unsafeWindow` is specific to userscript extensions like Greasemonkey.

Comment: Thanks you @Estus Flask, just 1 last thing would be possible? or i should stop trying?
if possible do you have any pointers. thanks

Comment: @ChopLabalagun I didn't touch extension development for a while so can't consult on the subject. But I don't think the problem you have is related to this question, it's very specific to user scripts and *monkey extensions. I'd suggest to ask a new one that is dedicated to your case.