# How to make a ViolentMokey userScript into a Browser Extension?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have been trying to migrate an userScript into my own extension but for some reason I am not able to run the following code:

```js
// ==/UserScript==
console.info('BEFORE Hooked! MONKEY');
(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Reference [Augular loaded detect]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31970556/9182265
    var initWatcher = setInterval(function () {
        if (window.MegaUtils) {
            console.info(window.MegaUtils);
            clearInterval(initWatcher);
            hookImport();
            hookFull();
            console.info('FUNtions Hooked! MONKEY');
        }
    }, 500);
})();
```

But for some reason the IF statement is never TRUE, but the same exact code is run from ViolentMonkey, it works right away.

So **window.MegaUtils** is not been detected at all and i have no idea why.
I was told that my extension might not have access to the DOM object but why ViolentMonkey does have access to it.

This is the manifest i am using when importing the extension in Chrome:

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "exclude_globs":    [  ],
        "include_globs":    [ "*" ],
        "js":               [ "mega.user.js" ],
        "matches":          [   "https://mega.nz/*",
                                "http://mega.nz/*" ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    } ],
    "converted_from_user_script": true,
    "description":  "testing extension",
    "permissions": [],
    "name":         "MegaByPass",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/mega-cloud-icon.png",
        "32": "images/mega-cloud-icon.png",
        "48": "images/download.png",
        "128": "images/873133.png"
      },
    "version":      "1.0"
}
```

[source](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/397876-mega-nz-ultimately-import/code)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is above code running? background script or content script? How is it injected?

Comment: I believe this is what you are asking: // @run-at       document-end
full source in: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/397876-mega-nz-ultimately-import/code

Comment: No. I was asking how des the adon inject the above script? via `manifest.json` or `tabs.executeScript` or `contentScripts.register()` or `userScripts.register()` etc?

Comment: that is a good question, i am using a manifest.json but not sure how ViolentMonkey does it. how to find that out?
I added my manifest to the question.

Comment: Reply updated again with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, remove the glob as it can cause issues.

```js
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://mega.nz/*", "https://mega.nz/*"],
    "js": ["mega.user.js"]
  }
]
```

ViolentMonkey injects by default at `document-end`. However, GM/VM/TM inject user-scripts manually and not using the dedicated API (FireMonkey in Firefox uses dedicated API), therefore the injection time may be later than when browser API injects.

Try with `"document_idle"` which is the default (you can leave it out).

Using `"document_end"` may result in the script running before the external Angualr is loaded and that can be the reason for the issue.

For proper testing, the actual extension is needed.

**Update 1**

Content scripts are injected into a different scope/context than the page that they are in. Therefore they can not directly interact with JS on the page and vice versa.

The global `window` behaviour is not uniform between different browsers (e.g. `eval()` in chrome always run in the context of the content script but in Firefox `eval()` runs in content scope but `window.eval()` in page scope).

After a quick testing, the content script doesn't have access to the global `window` & `window.MegaUtils`. There are ways to fix that but why the user-script works may have something to do with the way ViolentMonkey inject it or grants access to `window` object without using `unsafewindow`.

Have you tested the script with any other script managers?!! Does the script work on all script managers or only ViolentMonkey?

More Info:
[Accessing all the window variables of the current tab in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644906/accessing-all-the-window-variables-of-the-current-tab-in-chrome-extension)
[Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

*PS. I only tested on Firefox as I don't use Chrome.*

**Update 2**

Looking at [Can't find page variables when used GM_ functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160273/cant-find-page-variables-when-used-gm-functions), it appears that GM|TM|VM may be injecting user-scripts into the page contents when there is `@grant      none` (*needs proper confirmation*). That would explain why above user-script with `@grant      none` works and can get `window.MegaUtils` in GM|TM|VM (not FM). In that case you would need to inject the script in the page JS.

Here is an example:

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = `(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Reference [Augular loaded detect]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31970556/9182265
    var initWatcher = setInterval(function () {
        if (window.MegaUtils) {
            clearInterval(initWatcher);
            hookImport();
            hookFull();
            console.info('FUNtions Hooked!');
        }
    }, 500);
})();

....`;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

**Update 3 CSP**

At the moment, browsers adhere to page CSP (Content Security Policy) which is the issue you refereed to in the comment.
ref:
[[meta] Page CSP should not apply to content inserted by content scripts (V2 issue)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267027)
[CSP 'sandbox' directive prevents content scripts from matching, due to unique origin, breaking also browser features [Screenshots]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1411641)

There are ways around that but they are not standard and extensions shouldn't circumvent browser or page CSP.

Comment: Chrome will complain about removing matches and js fields so they have to be there to be able to import it.
I give it a try with document_idle but the same behavior it never detects that window.MegaUtils.

Comment: @ChopLabalagun For proper testing, the actual extension is needed.

Comment: You can get it from here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WFUfK7gl60rue-AweRc3qPPGeUGK6Hma?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChopLabalagun Answer updated.. although the issue is not solved.

Comment: thank you for trying, this is very weird. i was expecting a very straight forward integration.

Comment: Have you tested the script with any other script managers?!!
yes, i have tried GreaseMonkey,ViolentMonkey and TamperMonkey all work just fine but the idea was to avoid a 3rd party app.

Comment: @ChopLabalagun I asked about other script-manager to see if there was anything specific about ViolentMonkey (not to suggest using user-script)

Comment: thank you for your time, ill see if the link provided will take me somewhere but i am not JS developer so it might take me a while to get it.

Comment: @ChopLabalagun check Update 2

Comment: Thank you for your time, i am not sure if i am doing this wrong i am not a JS developer but when i did the modifications i got this:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' *.mega.co.nz *.mega.nz data: blob:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-GsXU05kU86ZbZmQ15AGDoOOUtnYnbKHnScj9JDmfWT4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
can you review if i did it right: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXyo5ZO1hviEYoQq0gd__IhuypSLiBUS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChopLabalagun Check Update 3 ..not a solution but just for information

Comment: Thanks, ill investigate to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: content_security_policy on the manifest did the trick, you'll be getting the answer to this. thank you for your time, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure user_script instead of content_script is the way to go.

> This API offers similar capabilities to contentScripts but with features suited to handling third-party scripts:

> - access to the window and document global values related to the webpage the user script is attached to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/userScripts

It works a bit different though, still trying to understand it :)